# Differences and similarities between Paymium, Mt.Gox,BitInstant and other major players, cryptocoins ?

Tags: transactions, mtgox, bitinstant

I start exploring the Bitcoin world and I get confused concerning :

- who does what,
- different cryptocoins available,

Any specific advantage to use one ? for example, no limit for transfer, low fee,...

In addition, it seems that Mt.Gox is a strong player but there is not challenger in this new growing business ?

Thanks for your help to clarify the basics !

Comment: I think you should use the search feature to learn about those companies and other cryptocurrencies. You've asked a whole lot in one question.

Comment: Hi Beginner JP and welcome! Like Colin says you should try to narrow the scope of the question. StackExchange is best suited for specific questions that have specific answers.